# Android: AsyncTask crashes while i switch the tabs fast

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I have a tab in which i populate listview with images from live url. I am sending an object of class that consists of imageView and url string as a parameter to async task. I've also did this for listview tab `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))` so that everytime i press that tab a refreshed activity is loaded. My async task looks like this with parameters `private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<MyTaskParams, Void, Bitmap>` now when i open listview tab and then switch to another and back to it again the app crashes with this message `Your application maybe doing too much work in its main thread`. Kindly help me with this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use "CANCEL" in the AsyncTask if the fragment or activity calls the onPause Method!

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

Comment: there is no onpause method for asynctask but i already did this @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
         cancel(true);
        } , still crashes

Comment: the onPause Method is in the Activity or Fragment, you are right that is not in the AsyncTask, but you can cancel the asynctask from activity of fragment!

Comment: it cannot cancel in the oncancel method of the task, because it doesnt know that it is canceled!!! in onCancel you can dispatch your other parameters or something...